# How to change python path from anaconda to default

Tags: python, linux, anaconda

I installed Anaconda and now there's a (base) before the shell username in the terminal. I am also not able to use the default python by python command in the terminal as it calls the anaconda python. Also can't switch the python interpreter in vs code. (Nothing happens when I try)Any way I can reset it back. I have python 3.8.2 as default in my Linux fedora os.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can go to your bashrc

`/etc/bashrc`

and add a new alias for your default python location which you'll use for calling default python.

```
alias python_default='.../bin/python3'
alias python_conda='.../bin/python3'
```